# How compatible is Werewolf: the Apocalypse 2e (1994) with pre-1994 sourcebooks?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse-2nd-edition

Werewolf: the Apocalypse 2e was released back in 1994. There are a number of sourcebooks that didn't get updated for the 2nd edition for quite a while - if at all. My question is:

**How compatible are the pre-1994 and 1994 WW:tA sourcebooks with Werewolf: the Apocalypse, 2nd edition (WW3600)?**

I'm especially - but not exclusively - curious about the compatibility of Werewolf Players Guide 1e (1993, WW3202), and Umbra: The Velvet Shadow (1993, WW3204).

*Note, please, that I'm not interested in any later editions here.* Think of this question as if I asked it back in 1994 with a freshly bought WW:tA 2e in my hands.

Comment: You have a Werewolf Player's Guide 1st edition?!

Comment: @Trish Apparently. I'm kind of old. Or a time traveller. ;D

Answer (score 3):

I've used the 1st ed Players Guide in a campaign of 2nd ed W:TA.

You'll have to decide if you want to include all the extra complications to char gen which the Players Guide (PG) has and 2nd ed WTA doesn't. Namely

- merits & flaws
- personality archetypes
- planetary aspects

Including them just makes the whole process more fiddly, and you'll need the 4 page version of the tribal character sheets to record it all. Also, be aware that there are additional merits & flaws in other sourcebooks. (I had a player who drove me bonkers asking questions about merits which were in books I didn't own). Personally, if I ran WTA again, I would ban the lot of them as too much book-keeping for the GM and too many contradictory character traits for the players to keep track of. But perhaps that's just my players :-)

There are also **lots** of extra gifts in the PG which aren't in 2e core rules. In the end I typed myself a list of **all** the relevant gifts (UK campaign, so US tribes were irrelevant) from the 2e core rules, PG and tribe books, so the players didn't have to look thru several books when choosing. Or at least knew what book and what page number. Some kind person has now put a much better, full list on the web:[Wyrmfoe's gift list](http://www.wyrmfoe.com/werewolf-gifts/)

The stuff on tribes and other shapeshifters in the PG has mostly been duplicated or expanded on in the various tribe/breed books. IIRC the Gifts are sometimes an exception to this - the PG might have some which are not in any other book.